# Problema al importar useNavigation o Link desde 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Instalé react-router-dom (6.5.0) entre las dependencias de mi proyecto, pero cuando quiero importar los hooks, no muestra nada de la dependencia.

No tengo nada extraño configurado, usando Vite y js. Si copio y pego algo como import {useNavigation} desde 'react-router-dom' y despues uso el hook, toda la pantalla se queda en blanco (el fondo es gris). Intenté instalar una versión anterior, instalar y desinstalar varias veces, incluido npm, pero nada cambia.
Instalé inclusive en el root del proyecto los node_modules. Y nada.

Dejo screens tal vez ayude.

[image: Link]

[image: Package.json]

[image: UseNavigation]

Answer (score 0):

Primero en la primer imagen en la linea 3 la importación de Link es de la siguiente manera:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Luego en la 3 foto el hook de `react-router-dom` es *useNavigate* y la importación es de la siguiente manera:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```